# anxious word for frowning

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word to say when someone frowns anxiously?
Example: You just wrote a song and sang it for the first time for your best friend. By the end of the song you look at your friend, unconfident and with your forehead wrinkled and eyebrows on a /\ shape, anxious to hear his opinion about it.

Comment: I don't understand how frowning and being *anxious* or *unconfident* can be synonymous with *happy* or *eagerly* here. A "happy word for frowning" sounds like an oxymoron to me . . .

Comment: Jason, I know it did sound oxymoron. I edited for a clearer understanding. What I'm trying to find out isn't a variant of frowning, but a word to describe the action of furrowing one's forehead as commonly to express anxiety. Like in the example I used, when you are unconfident and really want an opinion/answer and your face seems to hover with a hesitant "So... what you think?"

Comment: Your own term *anxious* seems to fit.

Comment: Isn't the term 'anxious frown' contradicting? I think "frown" particularly imposes disapproval, or do you mean only the word anxious would fit?

Comment: Sample sentence, please!

Comment: indeed ... sample sentence(s) pls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facial features are complex and often display mixed emotions.  You could use words like "contorted" or "paradoxical" to describe the facial feature(s) that you want highlight (along with anxiety) for the best resulting effect.

For example:

> "I looked at her anxiously with a contorted frown (or smile) to
>   receive her response, but the paradoxical strain on her brow gave it
>   all away."

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/contorted

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/paradoxical